# Reset images generated from dropdown menu on each click with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to reset the images each time the user changes the dropdown. The problem I'm having right now is that every time you set the dropdown to a number and click "Go", it keeps generating another image on top of the previous one.

I want it so that if someone selects "1" in the dropdown and then selects "5", the 5 images replace the previous 1 that the user selected instead of keeping that previous 1 image that it generated before.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```js
var answer = 0;
var counter = 0;

var pics = [
    "img/img1.jpg",
    "img/img2.jpg",
    "img/img3.jpg",
    "img/img4.jpg",
    "img/img5.jpg",
    "img/img6.jpg",
    "img/img7.jpg",
    "img/img8.jpg",
    "img/img9.jpg",
    "img/img10.jpg"
];

var descriptions = [
    "Image 1",
    "Image 2",
    "Image 3",
    "Image 4",
    "Image 5",
    "Image 6",
    "Image 7",
    "Image 8",
    "Image 9",
    "Image 10"
];


function quizcheck() {

    var answer = document.getElementById("question1").value;
    console.log("Dropdown value: " + answer);

    if (answer==0){
        counter++;
    }

    if (answer==1){
        counter++;
    }

    if (answer==2){
        counter++;
    }

    if (answer==3){
        counter++;
    }

    if (answer==4){
        counter++;
    }

    if (answer==5){
        counter++;
    }

    if (answer==6){
        counter++;
    }

    if (answer==7){
        counter++;
    }

    if (answer==8){
        counter++;
    }

    if (answer==9){
        counter++;
    }

    if (answer==10){
        counter++;
    }




if(answer == 1){
    for(i=0; i<1; i++){
    console.log("The loop has run " + (i+1) + " times");    
    document.getElementById("pics").innerHTML += "<figure><img src='" + pics[i] + "' ><figcaption>" +   descriptions[i] +   "</figcaption></figure>";
    // document.getElementById("mainButton").onclick = null;
}
    }


if(answer == 2){
    for(i=0; i<2; i++){
    console.log("The loop has run " + (i+1) + " times");    
    document.getElementById("pics").innerHTML += "<figure><img src='" + pics[i] + "' ><figcaption>" +   descriptions[i] +   "</figcaption></figure>";
}
    }

if(answer == 3){
    for(i=0; i<3; i++){
    console.log("The loop has run " + (i+1) + " times");    
    document.getElementById("pics").innerHTML += "<figure><img src='" + pics[i] + "' ><figcaption>" +   descriptions[i] +   "</figcaption></figure>";
}
    }

if(answer == 4){
    for(i=0; i<4; i++){
    console.log("The loop has run " + (i+1) + " times");    
    document.getElementById("pics").innerHTML += "<figure><img src='" + pics[i] + "' ><figcaption>" +   descriptions[i] +   "</figcaption></figure>";
}
    }

if(answer == 5){
    for(i=0; i<5; i++){
    console.log("The loop has run " + (i+1) + " times");    
    document.getElementById("pics").innerHTML += "<figure><img src='" + pics[i] + "' ><figcaption>" +   descriptions[i] +   "</figcaption></figure>";
}
    }

if(answer == 6){
    for(i=0; i<6; i++){
    console.log("The loop has run " + (i+1) + " times");    
    document.getElementById("pics").innerHTML += "<figure><img src='" + pics[i] + "' ><figcaption>" +   descriptions[i] +   "</figcaption></figure>";
}
    }

if(answer == 7){
    for(i=0; i<7; i++){
    console.log("The loop has run " + (i+1) + " times");    
    document.getElementById("pics").innerHTML += "<figure><img src='" + pics[i] + "' ><figcaption>" +   descriptions[i] +   "</figcaption></figure>";
}
    }

if(answer == 8){
    for(i=0; i<8; i++){
    console.log("The loop has run " + (i+1) + " times");    
    document.getElementById("pics").innerHTML += "<figure><img src='" + pics[i] + "' ><figcaption>" +   descriptions[i] +   "</figcaption></figure>";
}
    }

if(answer == 9){
    for(i=0; i<9; i++){
    console.log("The loop has run " + (i+1) + " times");    
    document.getElementById("pics").innerHTML += "<figure><img src='" + pics[i] + "' ><figcaption>" +   descriptions[i] +   "</figcaption></figure>";
}
    }

if(answer == 10){
    for(i=0; i<10; i++){
    console.log("The loop has run " + (i+1) + " times");    
    document.getElementById("pics").innerHTML += "<figure><img src='" + pics[i] + "' ><figcaption>" +   descriptions[i] +   "</figcaption></figure>";
}

    }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>Loops</title>

</head>

<body>

<br>

        <h3>Choose a number to determine how many images load in the gallery:
        <select id="question1">
            <option selected value="0">Choose an Answer</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        </h3>

<input type="button" id="mainButton" value="Load" onClick="quizcheck()"><br>

<section id="pics">
</section>

<p id="firstdisplay">
<p>
    
<script src="js/loop-gallery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent duplication, you can simply add cleanup of the tag content with this code - `document.getElementById("pics").InnerHTML='';` at the beginning of function `quizcheck()`.

```js
var answer = 0;
var counter = 0;

var pics = [
    "img/img1.jpg",
    "img/img2.jpg",
    "img/img3.jpg",
    "img/img4.jpg",
    "img/img5.jpg",
    "img/img6.jpg",
    "img/img7.jpg",
    "img/img8.jpg",
    "img/img9.jpg",
    "img/img10.jpg"
];

var descriptions = [
    "Image 1",
    "Image 2",
    "Image 3",
    "Image 4",
    "Image 5",
    "Image 6",
    "Image 7",
    "Image 8",
    "Image 9",
    "Image 10"
];


function quizcheck() {
    document.getElementById("pics").innerHTML = '';

    var answer = document.getElementById("question1").value;
    console.log("Dropdown value: " + answer);

    if (answer==0){
        counter++;
    }

    if (answer==1){
        counter++;
    }

    if (answer==2){
        counter++;
    }

    if (answer==3){
        counter++;
    }

    if (answer==4){
        counter++;
    }

    if (answer==5){
        counter++;
    }

    if (answer==6){
        counter++;
    }

    if (answer==7){
        counter++;
    }

    if (answer==8){
        counter++;
    }

    if (answer==9){
        counter++;
    }

    if (answer==10){
        counter++;
    }




if(answer == 1){
    for(i=0; i<1; i++){
    console.log("The loop has run " + (i+1) + " times");    
    document.getElementById("pics").innerHTML += "<figure><img src='" + pics[i] + "' ><figcaption>" +   descriptions[i] +   "</figcaption></figure>";
    // document.getElementById("mainButton").onclick = null;
}
    }


if(answer == 2){
    for(i=0; i<2; i++){
    console.log("The loop has run " + (i+1) + " times");    
    document.getElementById("pics").innerHTML += "<figure><img src='" + pics[i] + "' ><figcaption>" +   descriptions[i] +   "</figcaption></figure>";
}
    }

if(answer == 3){
    for(i=0; i<3; i++){
    console.log("The loop has run " + (i+1) + " times");    
    document.getElementById("pics").innerHTML += "<figure><img src='" + pics[i] + "' ><figcaption>" +   descriptions[i] +   "</figcaption></figure>";
}
    }

if(answer == 4){
    for(i=0; i<4; i++){
    console.log("The loop has run " + (i+1) + " times");    
    document.getElementById("pics").innerHTML += "<figure><img src='" + pics[i] + "' ><figcaption>" +   descriptions[i] +   "</figcaption></figure>";
}
    }

if(answer == 5){
    for(i=0; i<5; i++){
    console.log("The loop has run " + (i+1) + " times");    
    document.getElementById("pics").innerHTML += "<figure><img src='" + pics[i] + "' ><figcaption>" +   descriptions[i] +   "</figcaption></figure>";
}
    }

if(answer == 6){
    for(i=0; i<6; i++){
    console.log("The loop has run " + (i+1) + " times");    
    document.getElementById("pics").innerHTML += "<figure><img src='" + pics[i] + "' ><figcaption>" +   descriptions[i] +   "</figcaption></figure>";
}
    }

if(answer == 7){
    for(i=0; i<7; i++){
    console.log("The loop has run " + (i+1) + " times");    
    document.getElementById("pics").innerHTML += "<figure><img src='" + pics[i] + "' ><figcaption>" +   descriptions[i] +   "</figcaption></figure>";
}
    }

if(answer == 8){
    for(i=0; i<8; i++){
    console.log("The loop has run " + (i+1) + " times");    
    document.getElementById("pics").innerHTML += "<figure><img src='" + pics[i] + "' ><figcaption>" +   descriptions[i] +   "</figcaption></figure>";
}
    }

if(answer == 9){
    for(i=0; i<9; i++){
    console.log("The loop has run " + (i+1) + " times");    
    document.getElementById("pics").innerHTML += "<figure><img src='" + pics[i] + "' ><figcaption>" +   descriptions[i] +   "</figcaption></figure>";
}
    }

if(answer == 10){
    for(i=0; i<10; i++){
    console.log("The loop has run " + (i+1) + " times");    
    document.getElementById("pics").innerHTML += "<figure><img src='" + pics[i] + "' ><figcaption>" +   descriptions[i] +   "</figcaption></figure>";
}

    }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>Loops</title>

</head>

<body>

<br>

        <h3>Choose a number to determine how many images load in the gallery:
        <select id="question1">
            <option selected value="0">Choose an Answer</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        </h3>

<input type="button" id="mainButton" value="Load" onClick="quizcheck()"><br>

<section id="pics">
</section>

<p id="firstdisplay">
<p>
    
<script src="js/loop-gallery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I was glad to help :)